# What is the correct way of forcing maven to use HTTPS for maven central?

Tags: java, maven

Recently sonatype enabled maven central to support https ([background information](http://blog.sonatype.com/2014/07/ssl_connectivity_for_central/#.U_PBTrvbBv8)). I've now added the following snippet to my pom.xml to force using https everywhere:

```
<!-- force https -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Questions:

- Is this sufficient? Or will there be still http involved somewhere?
- Is this the correct way of doing it? As I've read that I should do this in the settings.xml instead. But then others using my (open source) project won't use the secure connection.

**Update**

It does not look sufficient as for e.g. the assembly plugin still HTTP is used:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) @ graphhopper-web ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
```

Comment: Might I ask why you are doing this? <s>Surely you wouldn't be contributing to open source projects while you're supposed to be *working*, while being afraid your employer might inspect the packets, would you? Nothing to hide, nothing to fear, buddy!</s>

Comment: Don't understand your question. This is to protect the users of my project from man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I was genuinely curious while exactly you were doing this, thanks for the answer that makes sense. The <s>...</s> thing is a <s>arcastic remark about unencrypted traffic and potentially nosy employers, HTTPS is good for that too :)

Comment: i use 


<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

and my problem solve mvn work and continue to download from  https

thanks

Comment: Additionally I had to modify eclipse, Maven / User Settings [Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Dyd.png)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is already fixed in latest maven 3.2.3! See the [changelogs](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/release-notes.html)!

So install maven 3.2.3 and do 'rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/*' for a better feeling ;)

Comment: I'm not getting which better feeling the removal of the local cache `~/.m2/repository` is going to bring.

Comment: If you downloaded any compromised jar

Answer (score 50):

You don't have to place it into all POMs one by one. I'd rather suggest to add the following code into **MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml** into `<profiles>` section:

```
<profile>
    <id>maven-https</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories> 
</profile>
```

This will be always an active setting unless you disable/override it in your POM when needed.

Answer (score 17):

You can do the following to force maven use single repo:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

You can find more info [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).

And also you can use authentication to the repo if you like, the info is [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html).

Comment: As I stated already in the question: but then others would have to setup this in their settings.xml as well. That would be ugly I think. Or is this possible in the pom.xml too?

Comment: settings and/or mirros is not accepted in pom.xml, or where do I have to put it there?

Comment: yeah you are right its not possible, but a chance that you upload the settings file to svn, and everybody else would have it

Comment: they would have it but they would need to place it correctly. maven was invented for ease setup so that is not an option for me.

Comment: they would only need to update their svn, nothing more

Comment: First i would suggest to start using a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva and configure such things at a central location  . Furthermore the settings.xml is the only location where such things should be configured and never within pom file.

Comment: That is all to complex, not for me of course, but for users trying my open source project.

Answer (score 6):

*Add below code in your pom.xml file and no need to remove local cache, It's works like a charm*

```
<distributionManagement>
       <repository>
          <id>Central Maven repository</id>
          <name>Central Maven repository https</name>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
       </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

> Maven update with terminal

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: There is no need to run with -U option.

Comment: @ScanQR, It's update the maven dependencies

Comment: @NizamMahammad `-U` is short for `--update-snapshots – Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories`. As long as you don't purge `~/.m2/repository/` before, releases and snapshots are not going to be updated, since they are already there. Only snapshot versions that do not exist in the local repo are downloaded. `-U` just overrides the "[**updatePolicy:** This element specifies how often updates should attempt to occur. \[...\] , `daily` (default), \[...\]](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)". ...cont'd...

Comment: ...cont'd... @NizamMahammad I'm not 100 % sure about the following: "_check for updated releases_" could refer to what never ever should be done anyway: deploying a different (updated) artifact with the same release version. Many remote repo managers don't allow that by default but can be configured to allow such.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same issue and tried all the possible ways by changing the proxies mapping but nothing works, finally i got the solution by adding the below code in setting.xml file in .m2 folder resolve the problem.

Note: Working fine for me without enable the proxy in setting.xml.

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Karussell, instead of deleting the whole **local repository**, you can fix it by deleting a specific package.

1. Install/Update maven to latest version (**>= 3.2.3**)
2. Go to your local repository directory (**~/.m2/repository**)
3. Delete all packages under **org.apache.maven**: `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/*`

By doing above steps, you will need to re-download some maven's packages, but doesn't need to re-download the whole packages.

Comment: Fantastic. This is the best solution with the least impact overhead, imo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked in a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69200179/12567365). Since NetBeans was not specifically covered in existing answers here, I am adding the following.

---

**Short Answer**

Upgrade Maven. The URLs you need to use (with the `https` protocol) will be provided in a suitably recent version of Maven. This is the simplest solution for older installations of NetBeans.

---

**Details**

For NetBeans 8.2, which uses version 3.0.5 as its bundled Maven version, you can upgrade Maven to at least version 3.2.3 (or later).

**Check the Current Version**

You can check which version of Maven is being used by NetBeans as follows:

- In the main menu, go to Tools > Options.
- Select the Java icon, and then the Maven tab below it.

[image]

**Install an Upgraded Version**

Download and install Maven - for example, from here:

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

The installation instructions are here:

https://maven.apache.org/install.html

**Update NetBeans**

Go back to the location in NetBeans shown in the above screenshot.

Click on the Maven Home drop-down and select "browse...". Navigate to the location where you installed the new version of Maven - for example:

```
E:\apache-maven-3.8.2-bin\apache-maven-3.8.2
```

You should now see the new version reflected in NetBeans.

Click OK.

Finally, re-try the failed build command.

Comment: NetBeans part was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

for resolve this error you can add new  Repository as https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

[image]