# Maven security (or lack thereof?)

Tags: security, maven

How can I be certain that if developer Alice creates and uploads maven package `com.example.alice:the-greatest` to maven central, and developer Bob includes that package as a dependency in their project `com.example.bob:almost-as-great`, Bob actually gets Alice's code, and evil genius Charlie can't modify the code somewhere in the journey between Alice and Bob? (Never mind how Charlie would actually do this; bribing someone with root@maven-central with a gazillion simoleons would do as an example)

Linux distros typically solve this problem by having Alice digitally sign the package, require that all packages in the distro are signed and distribute the signatures with the packages, so that Bob can check that the package he has received was indeed signed by Alice and not modified in transit.

I'm fairly new to maven, and apologize if this is a silly question, but none of the tons of files that have ended up in my `~/.m2` look even remotely like a `.sig` file or something like it.

(I asked this on #maven IRC but nobody responded.)

Comment: If you want answers ask on the users mailing list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

> To improve the quality of the Central Maven repository, we require you
>   to provide PGP signatures for all your artifacts

There's a plugin to verify the signatures: http://www.simplify4u.org/pgpverify-maven-plugin/index.html

Maven Central supports HTTPS as well

[What is the correct way of forcing maven to use HTTPS for maven central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393298/what-is-the-correct-way-of-forcing-maven-to-use-https-for-maven-central)

Comment: So the chain of custody is intact from Alice to Maven central, but the default is "Charlie has free reign" unless Bob includes something special in every one of his projects? And even then, I don't see how the plugin you mention can be configured with white or black lists of allowed authors.

Comment: P.S. Why isn't that a maven system setting, like for example `RequireSignature Always` in `/etc/pacman.conf` on Arch, or equivalent in other distros?

Comment: @JohannesErnst you're right in that maven should verify PGP signatures by default. Perhaps you can provide a patch for them ;) In the meantime, you can DRY you config by using a Company Super POM: http://www.mosabuam.com/2009/10/company-super-pom-a-maven-practice

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan It may not be as simple as that: there also needs to be a web of trust of some kind, otherwise Charlie can simply sign the changed package: the signature check passes, but it wasn't Alice's.