# Maven: Failed to transfer file XXX Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required

Tags: maven, https

I'm getting an unexpected 501 error code when building my maven project. The message says HTTPS is required but i haven't changed my settings.xml.

How can i check if something has changed in my configuration?

How can i get things to work?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is explained in [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-501-error)

1) In order to upgrade your maven version you can use the following URL https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi; you should extract this file in your PC and then point the extracted file in your IDE.

2) Or... if you're using a non-updated IDE you can install a newer version and maven should be configured automatically in the proper way; In my case, i was using Netbeans 8.2 and now i moved to 11.1, which uses https and works smoothly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your maven version. Maven Central has made the switch to only use HTTPS. Check out this article. https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Comment: The switch happened yesterday 1/15. It is truly to prevent MITM attacks during the build phase.

Comment: It is not necessary to update. For older Maven version you can force using HTTPS in the settings.xml as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784045/4807875.