# create a new Maven Web Application project ON NetBeans IDE 8.2 this error appear

Tags: maven, jsp, jsf, jsf-2.2

When I am trying to create a new Maven Web Application project ON NetBeans IDE 8.2 this error appear

```
cd C:\Users\NoonelovemE\Documents\NetBeansProjects; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_151\\jre" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7 -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=mavenproject1 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany.mavenproject1 -Dbasedir=C:\\Users\\NoonelovemE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" --batch-mode archetype:generate\""
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4.126s
Finished at: Thu Nov 12 08:36:05 GMT-05:00 2020
Final Memory: 6M/92M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\NoonelovemE\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

I try to solve it by going to setting.xml and change https to http nothing happened
And I try to add this

```
     <mirror>
      <id>mirror1</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>mirror1</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
```

Also, nothing happened

Any help?

Comment: look at this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766463/maven-failed-to-transfer-file-xxx-return-code-is-501-reasonphrasehttps-requ

Comment: Thank's i learn how to update maven and the problem solved