# java answer exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm running a program in Java JDK 8.2 using Netbeans but there is an error that says the maven link failed to be download or something, when I searched for the problem they said I should change all URLs from HTTP to HTTPS but I don't know where exactly I should change it.

so my question is where should I change the UMLs or what files should I download?

here are pictures of the article explaining what to do and the error occurring in Netbeans:

1. the atricle

[image]

2. The error

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Comment: See the NetBeans-specific answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69200638/12567365) for details. There are various alternatives also described in other answers for that question. But I think the easiest approach is to (a) install a newer version of Maven and then (b) configure NetBeans to use it, instead of the bundled (older) Maven version.

Comment: Or you can just [upgrade NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/) to a version which has a newer bundled version of Maven.