# Issue in Maven java swing build in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I am working on a Netbeans Maven Java Application in Netbeans. not able to build a java swing application. Dependency are not downloading in .m2 folder.

[image]

Comment: It looks like NetBeans is trying to download from the Maven central repository using `http`. It needs to use `https` as [documented here](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https). The easiest way to fix this is to upgrade your version of NetBeans, because that will come bundled with an upgraded version of Maven which does not have this issue.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade NetBeans, then try upgrading the version of Maven used by your current version of NetBeans. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69200638/12567365) for details. If that still does not help, then we ned more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.[image]

Add the above code in the setting.xml file (C:\Users\PC.m2\settings.xml)